# What counts as an "assist"?

Tags: team-fortress-2

While the TF2 Wiki does state:

> A kill assist is awarded to a player dealing a *fair* amount of damage
>   to an enemy before another team member finishes the enemy off.

It is ambiguous however.  Many times I have damaged an enemy before another player comes to finish them off, yet the killfeed only shows that person who received that kill, and no assist points being rewarded to me.

Here's a sample scenario that happened to me over the weekend playing TF2 as a scout:

1. I spot a Heavy enemy
2. Heavy enemy spots me.
3. I fire my Scattergun.
4. He fires his Minigun.
5. I die.
6. Killcam reads "Heavy --> Me"
7. Killcam reads "Heavy - 6HP"
8. Pyro teammate runs up.
9. Pyro incinerates Heavy.
10. Killcam reads "Pyro --> Heavy"

What "damage" do I have to do in order for it to count as an assist? Is it a numerical value? Or a percentage of the target's hp?

Comment: Medic get assists by healing. I think there is also a time between when you damage them and when they die.

Comment: Because I remember taking a heavy down to 6 hp as a scout, then a pyro comes over and immolates him to death.  The killfeed only shows the pyro getting credited the kill; no mention of any assists

Comment: It depends. I don't think there's a real "definition" (there probably is). I know medics get assists always, but, as you said, there are definitely times where other classes get the finishing 6 health, and it doesn't count, and other times where you chip 6 damage off and a spy gets a stab, and it counts. I'll look and see, but it does seem a tad random sometimes.

Comment: Also, to make things more confusing: What if 2 medics are healing a single heavy and none of them has activated kritz or ubercharge. Which one gets XP? :)

Comment: @Retrosaur When you hit that heavy maybe medic came and cured him a bit. That could explain no assist kill for you.

Comment: @brano88 the one who started healing the heavy first gets the assist.

Comment: But the heavy's the one not getting the kill, the pyro Killed the heavy, whereas I damaged him down to 6 hp.

Comment: @Retrosaur it sounds like the issue is that too much time passed between when you did the damage and when the pyro killed the heavy. If the heavy is not taking damage for more than a few seconds (not sure exact number) the assist wears off

Comment: I think you're suppose stay ALIVE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A kill assist is awarded to a player dealing a fair amount of damage to an enemy before another team member finishes the enemy off.](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Kill_assist)  In the case of the situation you mentioned above, it is probable too much time passed between your damage and the pyro's.  The kill assist mainly applies to situations of multiple teammates engaging an enemy at the same time, so the timer to get an assist is very short.